# Добавить в одну из форм возможность прикреплять файл

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, form

На лэнде расположено несколько форм. Возникла необходимость к одной из них добавить возможность прикрепить файл.

Сейчас без файла все работает так.

Пример формы:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="type" value="zamer" name="type">
    <input class="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input class="tel" name="tel" type="text" minlength="13">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <button>ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</button>                    
</form>
```

Часть скрипта:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = {
        'name':$(".name", $(this)).val(),
        'tel':$(".tel", $(this)).val(),
        'square':$("#square", $(this)).val(),
        'type':$(".type", $(this)).val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: form_data,
      success: function(){
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.success').fadeToggle();
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.success').fadeToggle();
        }, 2500);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Произошла какая то ошибка!");
      }
    }); 
});
```

И, собственно, mail.php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['tel'])) {$phone = $_POST['tel'];}
    if (isset($_POST['square'])) {$square = $_POST['square'];}

 $to = "mail@mail.ru";/ 
 $subject = "Сообщение с лендинга site.ru";
 $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="; 
 $message = '
     <h3>Сообщение с лендинга site.ru</h3>
     <p>Площадь кухни:<b> '.$square.'</b></p>
    <p>Имя отправителя:<b> '.$name.'</b></p>
    <p>Телефон: <b>'.$phone.'</b></p>';

$headers .= 'from: mail2@mail.by' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){    
   exit("Спасибо за заказ");                                     
}        
}
```

Что и где нужно написать, чтобы файл пришел на почту? Я сам не программист и все делал наугад.

Огромная просьба не давать ссылок. Напишите, пожалуйста, по возможности подробно, как для "полного чайника!

Comment: `FormData` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 1):

Пишу подробно:

```
var form_data = new FormData(this);
```

вместо

```
var form_data = {
    'name':$(".name", $(this)).val(),
    'tel':$(".tel", $(this)).val(),
    'square':$("#square", $(this)).val(),
    'type':$(".type", $(this)).val(),
};
```

PHP

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: А куда, пред чем или вместо чего это вставить? И это в скрипте. А что дописать и mail.php?

Comment: Перестала вообще почта приходить